# Javascript / Typescript - How to avoid duplicated code

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a piece of code that basically repeats itself. The only difference is the type of params and scan invokes this.getDbClient().scan(params) and query invokes this.getDbClient().query(params)

```
static scanTable = async (params: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.ScanInput) => {
    let items;
    let scanResults: any[] = [];
    do {
        items = await this.getDbClient().scan(params).promise();
        (items.Items || []).forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey !== 'undefined');

    return scanResults;
}

static queryTable = async (params: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput) => {
    let items;
    let scanResults: any[] = [];
    do {
        items = await this.getDbClient().query(params).promise();
        (items.Items || []).forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey !== 'undefined');

    return scanResults;
}
```

I tried to extract the function and use

```
async (params: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.ScanInput | DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput)
```

and then trying to do

```
if params instanceof DynamoDB.DocumentClient.ScanInput call `scan(params)`
else if params instanceof DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput call `query(params)`
```

but it seems that instanceof cannot be used

> ERROR: Property 'ScanInput' does not exist on type 'typeof
> DocumentClient'.ts(2339)
>
> ERROR: Property 'QueryInput' does not exist on type 'typeof
> DocumentClient'.ts(2339)

What can I do here to avoid duplications?

Comment: maybe this will help https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates 
You can check what exactly type is and then call necessary methods